# Need clarification on poison blobs

Tags: azure, azure-functions

From docs at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#poison

> When a blob trigger function fails...

What means "fails"? Fails to compile? Throws an unhandled exception?

It would be great to have some sample code of things NOT working. All the sample code shows things working, which thus fails to demonstrate failure modes in Azure Functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is referring to unhandled exception during a function execution (when actual processing of a blob occurs).

Functions is built on top of the webjobs sdk so much of that documentation is relevant, see [poison messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to#a-idpoisona-how-to-handle-poison-messages). I think this is more the level you were hoping for.

You can find some examples of error functions if you dig into the [script test samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/tree/dev/test/WebJobs.Script.Tests.Integration/TestScripts).